# Android text color selector

Tags: android, selector, nav, drawer

I have a navigation drawer and a text selector which works really well. But I have a Dark theme where this selector have to be another, So I switch the selector at the ListAdapter like this

```
textView.setTextColor(rowView.getResources().getColor(R.color.textselector_dark));`
```

But now if I choose the dark theme the pressed color doesn't show just the default
My text selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_activated="true"
    android:color="@color/pressed_text_color"/>
<item
    android:color="@color/default_color" />
```

Comment: Is your pressed color is same as theme color ? If not then your Dark theme is overridding android:color="@color/pressed_text_color" this property of all textviews.

Comment: <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppTheme2">
        <item name="android:textColor">#eeeeee</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
</resources>


this is how my themes.xml look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [setTextColor(ColorStateList)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(android.content.res.ColorStateList)).The normal [setTextColor(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(int)) sets the color for all states, as its JavaDoc clearly states:

> Sets the text color for all the states (normal, selected, focused) to
>   be this color.

Comment: ***setTextColor(ColorStateList)*** method does same thing which ***selector.xml*** does. Are you sure about this pro-grammatical implementation ?

Comment: thanks  I have to use  this:textView.setTextColor(rowView.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.textselector_dark));

Comment: Yeah its working what i wrote. I had to use getResources().getColorState instead of getColor and it works